# PHP : 'json_encode' from Database not showing any values

Tags: php, mysql, json

It's not a duplicate question about UTF-8 Unicode.
[image: My table is in utf-8 unicode]
I am new to php and I am trying to create a `json` response.
I added data into my database properly as follows. 
[image]
Then I tried to connect to DB and i did it successfully .
but after that when I tried to create a json response by using the following code, it doesn't shows any json response .

My PHP code is :

```
<?php
define('HOST','localhost');
define('USER','root');
define('PASS','qwerty');
define('DB','carol');

$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);
 if (!$con)
    {
      echo "Please try later..";
    }
else
    {
      echo "DB Connected..";
    }
$sql = "SELECT * from songs";
$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if (!$res)
    {
      echo "query failed..";
    }
else
    {
      echo "Query success..";
      echo (mysqli_num_rows($res));

    }
$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
array_push($result,
array('title'=>$row[0]),
array('url'=>$row[1]),
array('lyrics'=>$row[2])
);
}
echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

I'm getting only echo of **DB Connected , Query Success and 14 (no of rows)**
[image]

I'm trying PHP for the first time by using some online tutuorials.
if I did any mistake in my code,please help me to find my mistake.

Thank you in advance.

After I added `echo var_dump($res);`
I got [image]

Comment: show var_dump($result);

Comment: can you please post what you get if you add this line before your while loop:
mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
var_dump($result);
also the way you are pushing the values is for sure wrong, i'll include that in my answer

Comment: @KrisRoofe @flynorc : `object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) {
  ["current_field"]=>
  int(0)
  ["field_count"]=>
  int(3)
  ["lengths"]=>
  NULL
  ["num_rows"]=>
  int(14)
  ["type"]=>
  int(0)
}`

Comment: is your [PHP error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) turned on or off? do you get any errors if you turn on `error reporting`? also please add this line `var_dump($result);` before this line `echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));` and share the output for us

Comment: Also, sharing instead of screen shots from the results, you can simply copy and paste the result as text here.